# No member named 'setupUI' in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm designing a Qt Ui file to use it but in cpp file there's an error call 'no member named 'setupUi'. Has anyone dealt with this error before?

Header file:

```
#ifndef SCHEDULERSCAN_H
#define SCHEDULERSCAN_H

#include <QMainWindow>
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace SchedulerUi {
   class SchedulerScan;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE
class SchedulerScan : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
SchedulerScan(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~SchedulerScan();

private:
   SchedulerScan *ui;
};

#endif // SCHEDULERSCAN_H
```

Cpp file:

```
#include "schedulerscan.h"
#include "ui_schedulerscan.h"

SchedulerScan::SchedulerScan(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new SchedulerScan)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SchedulerScan::~SchedulerScan()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: "Has anyone dealt with this error before?" - quite likely, since Qt has been around for 20+ years. Did you actually link correctly with the Qt libraries you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two classes named `SchedulerScan`: the class you are writing, and the autogenerated UI class from the `ui_schedulerscan.h` (autogenerated). But the second class lives in the `Ui` namespace, so the full name of that class is `Ui::SchedulerScan`. Plus you forward-declare a `SchedulerUi::SchedulerScan` class that simply doesn't exist at all.

You're not actually following the typical idiom for using Qt forms, but it's close. The typical way of doing this with Qt is to include a pointer to the class in the `Ui` namespace in your class, and allocate that in the constructor, and then call `setupUi()` of that class.

But in your case you have a pointer to your *own* class there, which doesn't have a `setupUi()` method. And even if you added that method, you'd have created an endless loop by allocating an object of your own class in a *constructor* of your own class.

What you actually want to do is to follow the standard Qt pattern for this and make the class in the `Ui` namespace the member.

I've adjusted your header file to follow the typical pattern:

```cpp
#ifndef SCHEDULERSCAN_H
#define SCHEDULERSCAN_H

#include <QMainWindow>
namespace Ui {
   class SchedulerScan;
}
class SchedulerScan : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
SchedulerScan(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~SchedulerScan();

private:
   Ui::SchedulerScan *ui;
};

#endif // SCHEDULERSCAN_H
```

And your C++ file:

```cpp
#include "schedulerscan.h"
#include "ui_schedulerscan.h"

SchedulerScan::SchedulerScan(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::SchedulerScan)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SchedulerScan::~SchedulerScan()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Note that I've added the `Ui::` to the `ui` member's type declaration and the type provided to the `new` operator. I've also replaced the namespace of the forward declaration in the header file the `Ui` namespace, otherwise the pointer in the class won't compile. Furthermore I've removed the `QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` and `QT_END_NAMESPACE` macros in your header file, because they are used by Qt **internally** to optionally define a namespace for the Qt classes (depending on the build options). They shouldn't be used by users at all unless you are specializing a template of Qt.